# Send 1 request, Receive 2 Responses GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I want to trigger a request from an Apollo Server during (and dependent on the data returned from) a request that originated from the client. I want to return the data that was originally requested by the client, and later return the data from the request originating from the server to the client.

SERVER:

```
async function getPlaylistItems(playlistId) {
  const url = '... external api endpoint with query parameter playlistId=playlistId'
  const response = await axios(url, { method: 'GET' });
  // response.data = ['title1','title2',...]'
  const secondUrl = '...another external endpoint with response.data as query parameters'
    // create a new request (but don't wait for it to resolve) and return response.data to client
    const secondRequest = axios(secondUrl, { method: 'GET' });
    return response.data
}
```

CLIENT:

```
const playlist = getPlaylistItems('playlistId');
const secondRequestData = ...?
```

I want to receive the response from getPlaylistItems first, and send the response from secondRequest (on the server) back to the client once it resolves.

Here is a diagram of the desired data flow:
[image: diagram of desired data flow]

Answer (score 0):

The features you are looking for is [@defer directive](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/pull/2181). But right now it is under development and not possible to use it using apollo-server.

As far I know you there is no support available for returning partial response right now.

Or else you can use GraphQL Subscriptions if you really want to return the partial response.

More info about [@defer](https://blog.apollographql.com/new-features-in-graphql-batch-defer-stream-live-and-subscribe-7585d0c28b07)